# Celery tasks using specific sentry logger not working

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, sentry

Following sentry example for celery integration and using specific logger is not working as sentry is receiving any error or any logger.
Anyway to control loggers to send to sentry?

```
import logging
import celery
import raven
from raven.contrib.celery import register_signal, register_logger_signal
sentry_logger = logging.getLogger("logger_for_sentry")

class Celery(celery.Celery):

    def on_configure(self):
        client = raven.Client('https://<key>:<secret>@sentry.io/<project>')

        # register a custom filter to filter out duplicate logs
        register_logger_signal(client, logger=sentry_logger)

        # hook into the Celery error handler
        register_signal(client)

app = Celery(__name__)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

These are my logging settings, when I trace my_logger1 on web it work as expected and not sent to sentry, however in celery it is sent

```
LOGGING = {
     ...
    'loggers': {
        'sentry_logger': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'my_logger1': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },    
    }
}
```

Comment: I have sentry working ok  all loggers not only the one I have specified in register_logger_signal. Thats what i want

Comment: Show your `LOGGING` variable in django settings, please

Comment: Added `LOGGING` settings

Answer (score 0):

Set a `celery` logger in your django logging settings like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    # ...
    'loggers': {
        # ...
        'celery': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False,
            'handlers': ['console'],  # use only console for celery
        },
    }
}
```

In your `celery.py`:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set your real settings module instead `apps.settings`
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'apps.settings')  

app = Celery('ag')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Comment: I have already configures one logger with sentry handler the problem is celery is sending yo sentry other  loggers nota handler by sentry thats what i am trying to be specific

Comment: @JuanMadurga thanks for the explanation :) I updated the answer, please check

Comment: @AntonShurasov I am still receiving in sentry other logger not only the one configured `register_logger_signal(client, logger=sentry_logger)`